# asp.net mvc RedirectToRouteResult exclude hash value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, hash, routes

```
public class AuthorizeUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{   
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            "Error",            
            new RouteValueDictionary(
                        new
                        {
                            controller = "Error",
                            action = "Index"
                        })
                    );
    }
}
```

In RouteConfig I added new route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Error",
                url: "Error#/Error",
                defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Index" }
            );
```

If I open url like this:
http://localhost:52956/Home#/HomeAction and `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` is triggered, then url structure looks like this: http://localhost:52956/Error%23/Error#/HomeAction

How to redirect to http://localhost:52956/Error#/Error

PS Application is built using angularJS and asp.net mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragments are not part of .NET routing, they are only applied using the `UrlHelper` (which is what drives ActionLink and RouteLink). So, you could do this by using `UrlHelper`.

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(
    UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(
        routeName: "Error", 
        actionName: "Index", 
        controllerName: "Error", 
        protocol: null, 
        hostName: null, 
        fragment: "/Error", 
        routeValues: null, 
        routeCollection: null, 
        requestContext: filterContext.RequestContext, 
        includeImplicitMvcValues: false));
```

Alternatively, you could specify the URL explicitly.

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Error#/Error");
```

But either way, you need to fix your route. Browsers aren't required to send the fragment part of the URL back to the server (and many of them don't), so there is no way to reliably match it. The best you can do is match the path of the URL without the fragment.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Error",
    url: "Error",
    defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Index" }
);
```

This is assuming that no other URL in your application is `/Error`, otherwise you will have a conflict.